# IBM X3650 with Red Hat Enterprise 4.8 kernel panics with error on empty memory bank

Tags: linux, memory, ibm, kernel-panic

I have 3 IBM X3650 load balanced (round robin) with Red Hat Enterprise 4.8. One of them has intermittent kernel panics and reports an error on 2 particular memory banks (3 and 5) which are empty. I only have memory module on bank 1,4,7 and 10. I have tried to replaced all my memory modules to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If they're identical machines and you can afford the downtime consider shutting down the 'bad' server and a working server, swapping their disks, bringing them up again and seeing if the problem moves with the disks or stays with the hardware. If the former you have a disk/OS issue, if the latter you have a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel panics usually indicate a hardware problem.

The banks 3 and 5 are empty: did you try to clean (with compressed air, (from a high position in order not to damage the card)) the memory slots area?

If the 3 machines have the same kernel version, configuration and software, it sounds like it is likely to be a motherboard problem: is the firmware version identical on the 3 motherboards?

Answer (score 0):

We just had a similar issue this week with an x3650 (M/T : 7979)

We were running BIOS v. 1.03 (which shipped with the system). Support recommended upgrading the BIOS - we had two systems in a similar load balanced setup, but the configurations drifted. One server had BIOS v. 1.15 and the other one was running a very old version of the BIOS. The older version BIOS system was the one with the issues.

The [BIOS changelog](http://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/XSA/00mp0/0/ibm_fw_bios_gge145a_anyos_i386.chg) cites several issues which were fixed with regards to memory. I recommend upgrading the BIOS using updateXpress or the Bootable Media Creator. If that doesn't work, dial 1800IBMSERV.

You can check your BIOS version by installing the IBM DSA (available at [fix central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/)) utility and running (as root)

```
./opt/IBM/DSA/bin/biosversion
```

Comment: Running dmidecode should show the various BIOS/BMC/IMM/UEFI versions on IBM servers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, errors from non-existent DIMMs do look like a motherboard fault.
But it may be easier to try BIOS update first.  AFAIK x3650 BIOS allows to reduce memory speed, which is also worth trying out.